# API callback not working as soon as I insert ${city}, ${country} to query for weather on open weather API

Tags: reactjs, api, asynchronous, async-await, openweathermap

Here is my api call-- error recieved is value is undefined, probably refering to my city and country variables?? help?

```
    goGetWeather = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const city = e.target.elements.city.value
    const country = e.target.elements.country.value
    const api_call = await fetch(
    `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? 
    q=${city},${country}&appid=8004ed6a9e53c30dd054d07
    9fff7f24e&un 
    its=metric`
    )
    const data = await api_call.json()
    console.log(data)
```

render() {
    return (

```
    <Weather
      city={this.state.city}
      country={this.state.country}
      description={this.state.description}
    />
    <br />
  </div>
)
```

}
}
export default App

Comment: hi aamirl, sorry just noticed your post --> yeah, after a lot of staring I realized I had form-controll atrributes on my inputs in child comonent ... works great now.. I do however need to learn how to scfreenshare better ;)

Answer (score 0):

I removed the form-control attrinutes from my inputs in childcomponent --works now